# has_many through several times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I would like to have an advice about my code because I'm not sur to well use the has_many trough association.

In my case Users can mark as view a Post. 
They can comments Posts and they can also write notes about Posts.

This is what i have done:

```
class User 
  has_many :posts, through: post_views
  has_many :posts, through: comments
  has_many :posts, through: notes
end

class Post
  has_many :users, through: post_views
  has_many :users, through: comments
  has_many :users, through: notes
end

class PostView
  belongs_to: user
  belongs_to: post
end

class Comment
  belongs_to: user
  belongs_to: post
end

class Note
  belongs_to: user
  belongs_to: post
end
```

Is it ok ? What can I do to have a better code ?

Edit = after Mohammad AbuShady answer
    class User 
      has_many :post_views
      has_many :viewed_posts, through: :post_views

```
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commented_posts, through: comments

  has_many :notes
  has_many :noted_posts, through: notes
end

class Post
  has_many :post_views
  has_many :viewer_users, through: post_views

  has_many :comments
  has_many :comments_users, through: comments

  has_many :notes
  has_many :notes_users, through: notes
end


class PostView
  belongs_to: user
  belongs_to: post
end

class Comment
  belongs_to: user
  belongs_to: post
end

class Note
  belongs_to: user
  belongs_to: post
end
```

is ok ?

thanks

Lokhi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the relation with the join model for the `through` part to work, so

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_views
  has_many :viewed_posts, through: :post_views
end
class PostView < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :posts
  belongs_to :users
end
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_views
  has_many :users, through: :post_views
end
```

And the same for the other two models.